# Which `Clock` implementation is the default in java.time?

Tags: java, clock, java-time

The *java.time* framework built into Java 8 and later includes the [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) class. This class provides several variations useful for testing our date-time handling code.

```
Instant.now( Clock.fixed​( myInstant , myZoneId ) )
```

Which `Clock` instance represents the default used implicitly in *java.time* calls where we do not specify a `Clock`?

```
Instant.now()
```

I imagine the default is either:

- [`systemDefaultZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#systemDefaultZone())
- [`systemUTC()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#systemUTC())

…but the documentation does not say which.

When doing unit-testing, sometimes we need a clock with altered behavior. But when we want to explicitly pass a `Clock` object that gives default behavior, what do we use?

Comment: Given that an `Instant` has no time zone, does it matter which it uses?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Source code of `Instant.now()`<sup>1</sup>, which you could easily find yourself if you use an IDE<sup>2</sup>:

```java
public static Instant now() {
    return Clock.systemUTC().instant();
}
```

<sup>*1) Copied from OpenJDK 14*</sup>
<sup>*2) In Eclipse, you place cursor on `now()` and press F3 to see the source code. 
In IntelliJ, press F4, or choose View > Jump to Source, or on a Mac ⌘+click.*</sup>

It is guaranteed that all compliant versions of Java will do it that way, since it is part of the contract defined for the method, i.e. it is so **documented** in the javadoc of [`now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#now()):

> This will query the [system UTC clock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#systemUTC()) to obtain the current instant.

That link leads to [`Clock.systemUTC()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#systemUTC()).

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all JDKs implement this method in the same way?

Comment: The answer is correct for `Instant.now()`, the method asked about. For a broader picture, some other classes use `systemDefaultZone()`. For example the no-arg `ZonedDateTime.now()` is implemented as `return now(Clock.systemDefaultZone());`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Good point, but the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`ZonedDateTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now()) says that too: *"This will query the [system clock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#systemDefaultZone()) in the default time-zone to obtain the current date-time"*, where the link leads to `Clock.systemDefaultZone()`. --- ***Moral:*** Don't assume, always read the documentation to *make sure* you understand what the method does.

Comment: @ruakh All implementations of Java must follow the published class API. However, the implementation of `Clock.systemUTC()` may vary, and certainly would vary across platforms as it must natively call the host OS’ clock facility.